# How to compare image string (name?) and change the image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimage

In IOS (iPhone) - I want to show the user an Image, he should write a text string (like the image name or something), If he writes the right string the image changes to a different image, if he makes a mistake and type the wrong string, nothing happens

Answer (score 4):

take user's entered string into

```
NSString *imageName = userTxtField.text;

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

if(image != nil){

  // change previous image

}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are trying to build an app like "Brands"

Once user types and press submit button compare imagename with user string

```
if([textField.text isEqualToString:IMGNAME]) {
    imageview.image = nextimage;
 }
```

Comment: OK, did you get solution or are you looking for it?

Comment: Since you show me the quiz-app , now I'm trying to figure how to do the whole package

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ImageNamed](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed%3a) function of [UIImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. 
If return value is nil then an image doesn't exist.
For example:

```
-(UIImage*)getImageNamed:(NSString*)name{
    UIImage* Image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
    if (!Image)
       NSLog(@"Sorry, there is no image named %@.",name");
    return (Image);
}
```